# What causes this error message "SELinux: Disabled on system, not enabling in X server" when running Xvfb?

Tags: linux, fedora, graphics

I am trying to run Xvfb :1 in Fedora 11 on a headless server, but I get the following error message:
SELinux: Disabled on system, not enabling in X server
(EE) config/hal: NewInputDeviceRequest failed (2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are those two separate lines? I think so. The first one, about SELinux being disabled, is just an informational message. The second, `(EE) config/hal: NewInputDeviceRequest failed (2)`, looks to me like [this bug or a close relative](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=511809).

And the fix, really, is: please upgrade your system from Fedora 11, which, as the bug entry notes, reached End Of Life in June 2010, almost half a year ago. If you need a longer OS lifecycle, consider CentOS or Ubuntu LTS (or pay for RHEL). I'm not saying this to be whiny, (and it appears unfortunate that this bug was never fixed in F11), but running an unsupported release on your server is just asking for future trouble.